# QGIS: \ in my expression gets returned as a?

Tags: qgis

Right now I am building a expression in a column I am gonna be using later. You see I have a problem where a expression in one of my columns this one:

```
'\gpkg_content.dbf'
```

Gets returned as this.

```
?pkg_content.dbf
```

So my \ is always converted to a ? while clearly I did not clarify that.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I am using just in field calculator. I am just trying to get the string \gpkg_content.dbf' for a contenation later to construct a filepath.

Comment: You need to use `\\\` to get a single backslash.

Comment: `\a` is a bell character which doesn't print well so it comes out as a `?`

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that backslashes in literals are treated as [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C), so `'\gpkg_content.dbf'` being treated as escape sequence `\g` (which I think is invalid, hence the `?`) followed by `pkg_content.dbf`.

You can use `\\` instead of `\` to represent an actual backslash. Or you could try `/`: QGIS on Windows is pretty good at accepting UNIX-style forward-slash rather than backwards-slash filenames, though there are some gaps and it may depend on what you do with the output of the expression later.

Note this all applies to literals specified in `''`. A `\` is not treated as an escape character if it comes from a field, for instance.